# Characterization of weak solution

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

> ### 5 Nonlinear elliptic variational inequalities
>
> #### Preliminaries
>
> In order to explain the importance of elliptic variational inequalities, first consider the weak solution of the linear elliptic function $(1.1)$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition, i.e. a function $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ satisfying for all $v\in H^1_0(\Omega)$
>
> $$\langle Au,v\rangle=\sum^n_{j,k=1}\int_{\Omega}a_{jk}(D_ku)(D_jv)dx+\int_\Omega cuvdx=\int_\Omega fvdx=\langle F,v \rangle\tag{5.1}$$
>
> It is well-known (see, e.g., $[67]$) that if $c\ge0,\;a_{kj}=a_{kj}\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ satisfy the uniform ellipticity condition then the unique solution is $u\in  H^1_0(\Omega)$ of $(5.1)$ is the unique function $u=u^\star\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ which minimizes the quadratic functional
>
> $$E(u)=\langle Au,u\rangle-2\langle F,u\rangle=\tag{5.2}$$
>   $$\sum^n_{j,k=1}\int_{\Omega}a_{jk}(D_ku)(D_ju)dx+\int_\Omega cu^2dx-2\int_\Omega fudx.$$
>   (Here $A:V\to V^\star$ is a linear operator, $V=H^1_0(\Omega)$.)
>
> Similarly, the weak solution of the Neumann problem with homogeneous boundary condition, i.e. the solution $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ of $(5.1)$ for all $v\in H^1(\Omega)$
>   , is the unique $u=u^\star\in H^1(\Omega)$ where $E$ attains its minimum in $H^1(\Omega)$. By using similar arguments as in $[67]$, one can show the following generalization of the above statements.

In the weak formulation of a linear elliptic PDE we have the following characterization of the unique solution $u \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$. In the attached image it is the part that reads "...the unique solution $u \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ of (5.1) is the unique function $u=u^{*} \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ which minimizes the quadratic functional..." Does anyone know how this characterization follows or a good book as a reference? The book that is recommended is in Hungarian and not easily available. Thanks.

Comment: From the note it looks like for unique $u \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ solving $Au = f$ iff unique $u$ minimizes $E(u) := \frac{1}{2}\langle Au,u \rangle - f(u)$...so it is a sufficient and necessary condition...? The answer below just says necessary condition.

Comment: It is necessary and sufficient, see the edited answer.

Comment: @daw Okay I see. Do you know why the $u$ is taken as being unique?

Comment: It follows from strict convexity of $E$, see also my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Rewrote the answer for more clarity.

Assume that $A$ is symmetric and coercive:
$$
\langle Au,v\rangle = \langle Av,u\rangle\quad \forall u,v\in H^1_0(\Omega),
$$
and
$$
\langle Au,u\rangle \ge \delta \|u\|^2 \quad \forall u\in H^1_0(\Omega)
$$ 
with some $\delta>0$.

We want to prove the following: Let $u^*\in H_0^1(\Omega)$. Then
these two points are equivalent:

1. $Au^*=f$.
2. $u^*$ minimizes $E(u):=\frac12\langle Au,u\rangle - f(u)$.

First observe, that the following identity holds:
$$
E(v) - E(u)= \langle Au-f, v-u\rangle + \frac12\langle A(v-u), v-u\rangle
$$ for all $v,u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$.
This can be derived by equivalent algebraic operations. If you know about differentiability, this is just the Taylor expansion of $E$ at $u$.

Let now (1.) be satisfied. Hence, it holds
$$
\begin{split}
E(v) - E(u^*)& =\langle Au^*-f, v-u^*\rangle + \frac12\langle A(v-u^*), v-u^*\rangle\\
&\ge \delta \|v-u^*\|^2,
\end{split}
$$
which implies $E(v)>E(u)$ for all $v\ne u$, hence (2.) holds.

Let (2.) be satisfied. Then
$$
E(v) - E(u^*)  =\langle Au^*-f, v-u^*\rangle + \frac12\langle A(v-u^*) \ge 0
$$
for all $v$. Take $h\in H^1_0(\Omega)$. Set $v:=u^*+th$ with $t>0$, divide 
the resulting inequality by $t$, let $t$ go to zero, to conclude
$$
Au^*=f,
$$
which is (1.).

Hope this helps.

Comment: So you are saying that $\text{min}\frac{1}{2}\langle Au,u \rangle - \langle f, u \rangle \Rightarrow u \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ such that $Au = f$? Could you give a hint as to how coercivity is used? Thanks

Comment: Coercivuty is used to ensure the existence of a minimum for $E$.

Comment: @daw So the idea is to show that $E(v) - E(u) \geq 0$ for all $v \in H_{0}^{1}$

Comment: @Siminore I'm stuck at this point, am I on the right track? $E(v)- E(u) = \frac{1}{2}\langle Av,v \rangle - \langle f,v \rangle 
- [\frac{1}{2}\langle Au,u \rangle-\langle Au,u \rangle] 
= \frac{1}{2}\langle Av,v \rangle - \langle f,v \rangle + \frac{1}{2}\langle Au,u \rangle
= \frac{1}{2}\langle Av,v \rangle - \langle Au,v \rangle + \frac{1}{2}\langle Au,u \rangle
\geq \frac{1}{2}C \Vert v \Vert^{2} - \langle Au,v \rangle + \frac{1}{2}D\Vert u \Vert^{2}$

Comment: see the edited answer

Comment: @daw thanks for your response. Is the first line some kind of taylor expansion? How did you evaluate $E'(u)$?

Comment: It is Taylor expansion.

Comment: @daw Okay but why did you only expand to three terms? Also could you lastly tell me how you expanded $E^{'}(u)$? Thanks for all the assistance.

Comment: Rewrote the answer to address your questions.

Comment: @daw Thanks for the edited answer, very helpful.

For the second implication, (2) implies (1). Is the following the correct working:

$\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow o^{+}} \frac{E(u^{*}+th)-E(u^{*})}{t} = \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow o^{+}} \frac{t\langle Au^{*}-f,h \rangle + \frac{1}{2}t^{2}\langle A(h),h \rangle}{t} = \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow o^{+}}[\langle Au^{*}-f,h \rangle + \frac{1}{2}t\langle A(h),h \rangle] = \langle Au^{*}-f,h \rangle \geq 0$

Comment: @daw 
Therefore $\langle Au^{*},h \rangle \geq \langle f,h \rangle$

Taking $-h$ we get the reverse inequality $\langle Au^{*},h \rangle \leq \langle f,h \rangle$ Therefore it follows that $Au^{*} = f$.

Could I ask where exactly the differentiability and Taylor series you mentioned are used?                                                  Is it used to show $E(v)-E(u^{*}) \geq \delta \Vert v -u \Vert^{2}$ as you have it in the proof of the first implication?

Comment: Your calculations are right. Differentiability and Taylor series is not explicitly use, but it is behind the scenes ;)

Comment: @daw For the first implication I get $E(v)-E(u^{*}) = \langle Au^{*}-f,v-u^{*} \rangle + \frac{1}{2}\langle A(v-u^{*}),v-u^{*} \rangle = 0 + \frac{1}{2}\langle A(v-u^{*}),v-u^{*} \rangle$ (do you then assume that $A$ is a positive definite operator to get) $ \geq \delta \Vert v-u^{*} \Vert^{2}$? It doesn't state that $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: It follows from $c\ge0$, uniform ellipticity, and Friedrichs inequality.

Comment: @daw Yes I see how it follows now. Instead of Friedrich's inequality we could also use Poincare's inequality.

Comment: @daw Hi sorry to bother, but I just want to confirm that for weak derivatives you don't require the  lower order derivatives to exist in order for the higher order derivatives to exist?